# Devolper console not showing reviews

Tags: android, review

How do I see all reviews for my android-app. I currently have 50 ratings, but can only see around 10 written reviews. How to I see all written reviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may only have 10 written ratings. To rate your app (1-5 stars) a user DOES NOT have to do any more than that. In other words, they don't have to write anything but they can still give you X number of stars which affects your overall rating.